# When taking a shot from web cam my code sometimes stretches or cuts off the picture

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, webcam, getusermedia

I made a web application that should allow me to take a picture from the web camera.

How should the application work:

✓ Run the web app from the Chrome browser on the mobile device.

✓ Grant the permissions to the web app [to access camera ]. This should grant me an access to the front and back camera as I desire.

✓ Camera comes on and is being displayed within

```
<video id = 'camera' style="margin: 0 auto; width:320px;"></video>
```

✓ Now I am able to take snaps from the web camera by pressing a button. Whenever I take a snap I draw it on the hidden canvas.

```
<div><canvas id = 'c'class="hidden"></canvas></div>
```

By using this code:

```
grabFrame(vm) {
var imageCapture = new ImageCapture(window.stream.getVideoTracks()[0]);
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var orientation = window.screen.orientation.type;
if (orientation === "portrait-secondary" || orientation === "portrait-primary") {
  canvas.height = 640;
  canvas.width = 480;
}
else {
  canvas.height = 480;
  canvas.width = 640;
}
imageCapture.grabFrame(vm).then(function (imageBitmap) {
  // if this is a device running on windows touch device
  if ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("windows") > -1) &&
      (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("touch") > -1)) {
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(imageBitmap, 0, 0);
  }
  else {
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(imageBitmap, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }
  canvas.classList.remove('hidden');
  var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  vm.get('photos').pushObject(img);
  canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
});}
```

I draw the `Captured Image` on the canvas and then I am adding it to the array of pictures that I need for further use.

Firstly, I tried to use `takePhoto()` function from [here](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/image-capture/grab-frame-take-photo.html) but it simply didn't work at all.

My code **works** but not fully when it comes to scaling the picture and orientation.

✘ If I use Window Tablet to take the photo, photo taken in **portrait mode** looks fine but horizontal one is cut off.

[image]

I think I am twisting something up but I just don't understand why everything works fine on **Android** and it does not on **Windows tablet**.

On both devices I was using Chrome browser with the same version 58++.